# Datastudio split and convert a string

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field

I do have a Dimension which contains ex: `campaign-20022020` the numbers are the date on which the campaign started.
I've sliced the string into `20022020` with `SUBSTR(Campaign, -8, 8)`

How do I manage to convert the Date `20022020` which is `DDMMYYY` to `DD-MM-YYYY`
In Datastudio the default settings are `YYYYMMDD`

I've tried `TODATE(Campaign Split, "%d-%m-%Y", "%d%m%Y")` (Campaign Split is the field from Campaign which I've split) but that gives me a `null Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single calculated field does the trick:

```
TODATE(SUBSTR(Campaign, -8, 8), "%d%m%Y", "%Y%m%d")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/63fb2c5a-e5ee-4154-b7af-d201b9bbe442) to demonstrate.

[image: 2]]